# jquery selectors: applying function only to current element

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I have a jquery function that happens on focus for all inputs with a given class. It works great except when its applied, it applys to all inputs with that class. How can I apply the function only to the one that triggered the action?

Please see my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xi4xi4/sv9uZ/2/)

(when date is clicked, all of them clear. Also if you have entered 1, the other does not return to the default hint)

Many thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `$(this)`

```
$('.inputDay').focus(function() {         
    if ($(this).val() == "dd") {
        $(this).val("").css("color", "#000000");
    }
});
```

Working sample :  http://jsfiddle.net/sv9uZ/3/  ( I fixed the other code to use chaining also)

**EDIT :**  To Avoid Calling `$(this)` everytime ( since we use more than once), We can store that to a local variable and use that. Thanks [Mathletics](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7469/mathletics) for bring it up.

```
$('.inputDay').focus(function() {
    var item=$(this); 
    if (item.val() == "dd") {
        item.val("").css("color", "#000000");
    }
});
```

Comment: cache your selection for extra performance! `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: @Mathletics: I updated the answer to include that for future reference. Thanks `Matheletics` for bringing it up.

Comment: Make sure you declare it in scope with `var` so that it doesn't become an auto-global. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1455724/7469

Answer (score 1):

Just say $(this).val <-- instead of using class. This will apply only for current one

Giving a class name will apply for all matching ones. Saying this instead will apply only to the currently modified one

Comment: See what I did there! - 'this'

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered but generally when I do this, I store the value that I want greyed out in the input's title attribute, which would allow you to cut down on some code and do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.inputDay, .inputYear').focus(function(e){
    $this = $(this);
    $this.val() == $this.attr('title') ? $this.val('') : '';     
    $this.css("color", "#000");
  }).blur(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.val().length){
      $this.val($this.attr("title")).css("color", "#999");
    }
  });

  $('.inputDay, .inputYear').trigger('blur');    
});
```

That way you don't have to tie the function to any specific values like "dd" or "yyyy" so it can be reused.

For a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Wjmav/1/